# How to make the button on the CSS

Tags: html, css

How to make this button in css that is not stupid to expose background-image and impose it

[image]

```css
a {
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 372px;
  height: 65px;
  border-radius: 48px/34px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, #ec643b, #e15b3a);
  box-shadow: 0 -3px #dc3d18, 0 -5px #ff7f44, 0 -7px #fb7039;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"></a>
```

Comment: Please check this link:-http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/going-crazy-with-css3-issue-1-creating-buttons-with-linear-background-borders

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of display the button through anchor or button.

Try this:

```css
  

 a {
     background: #fb9600;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px inset;
        color: #fff;
       padding: 8px;
       transition: background-color 0.4s linear 0s;
        width: 100%;
     max-width:150px;
    }
    
    
   



    button {

     background: #fb9600;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px inset;
        color: #fff;
       padding: 8px;
       transition: background-color 0.4s linear 0s;
        width: 100%;
     max-width:150px;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#">NEXT</a>
<h5>Next solution</h5>
<button>NEXT</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
button{
    width: 401px;
    height: 75px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    background: #db5035;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 12px 5px #de3d16;
    border: 0px;
    border-top: 5px solid #ff8841;
  }
body{
  background:#000;
  }
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: @G_test_00 check now

Comment: @G_test_00 probably this is works for you,check it now

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  margin: 10%;
}
a {
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 359px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, #ec643b, #e15b3a);
  box-shadow: 0 -3px #dc3d18, 0 -5px #ff7f44, 0 -7px #fb7039;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href="#">Submit</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok my bad what you are then looking for because your styling seems working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should named a button `<button ID='btnone'>Submit</button>`
Next in .css file you should recall `btnone` like:

```
#btnone {
Enter code here
}
```

I use `ul` and `li` to create menu's buttons.